# How to convert (text of code) to typeitjs typing

Tags: javascript, typeit

For example .. i have this code of javascript

```
function first(){
    function second(){
        function third(){

        }
    }
}
```

and this paragraph `<p id="hero"></p>`

[typeitjs](https://typeitjs.com/)

How to split code to be like this on [typeitjs](https://typeitjs.com/) typing:

```
new TypeIt("#hero", {
  speed: 50,
  startDelay: 900
})
.type(`function first() {}`)
.move(-1)
.type(`function second() {}`)
.move(-1)
.type(`function first() {}`)
.go();
```

Final result p#hero is :

```
function first(){
    function second(){
        function third(){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done to achieve your expected results? The tutorial is pretty obvious and you should ask for a help with specific issues, not just "write it for me" :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here I present my solution.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      new TypeIt("#element", {
        speed: 50,
        starDelay: 900,
      })
      .type("function first() {")
      .break()
      .type("\tfunction second() {")
      .break()
      .type("\t\tfunction third() {")
      .type("<br>")
      .break()
      .type("\t\t}")
      .break()
      .type("\t}")
      .break()
      .type("}")
      .go(); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typeit@8.0.2/dist/index.umd.js"></script>
<pre id="element"></pre>
```